# Path not found in perl

Tags: shell, perl

I want to obtain names of owners of files, that are in specified directory (2 in the loops is just for testing, there are only 2 files in my /media anyways). So, if user's input is "/media", i get the following output:

> ```
> sh: 2: /kuba: not found
> sh: 2: /sf_Shared: not found
> root:kuba
> ```

So it seems, that the script works, but displays "not found" anyways.

```
my $directory =<STDIN>; #"/media";
my @ls = qx(ls $directory);
chomp @ls;
my @fow;
for(my $i = 0; $i < 2; $i++ )
{
        $fow[$i] = qx(stat -c '%U' $directory/$ls[$i]);
        #say $fow[$i];

}
chomp @fow;
print "$fow[0]:$ls[0]\n";
```

BTW, When I remove user's input and just declare $directory as "/media", it works perfectly fine.

Comment: You must [chomp](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/chomp) the `$directory` data.

Comment: `my $directory =<STDIN>;` will give you `/media\n`, without stripping `\n` your OS will not find the directory.

Comment: Using `chomp()` to remove the newline from data read from `<STDIN>` is, in general, a very good idea. But in this case, it's not necessary as the string (with the newline attached) is passed to `qx(ls $directory)`. And the shell that executes the command doesn't care that there's a newline on the end. Try `perl -lE '$dir = ".\n"; say qx(ls $dir)'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the easiest approach is something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';
use File::stat;

# Default to the current directory if one isn't given on
# the command line.
# Note: "defined-or" operator so we don't fail on a
# directory called "0"
my $dir = shift // '.';

# Use \Q...\E around the directory name to make life easier
while (my $file = glob("\Q$dir\E/*")) {
  say $file;
  # File::stat changes the behaviour of stat() and makes
  # it far easier to use
  my $uid = stat($file)->uid;
  my $user = getpwuid($uid);

  # Simple output option :-)
  say "$file / $user";
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Why do not use perl instructions instead of shell calls which is an expensive on resources?

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $dir = shift || die "Provide a directory name";
my($file, $owner);

while( glob("$dir/*") ) {
        $file  = $_;
        $owner = getpwuid((stat($_))[4]);
        write;
}

$~ = 'STDOUT_BOTTOM';
write;

exit 0;

format STDOUT_TOP =
+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
| File                                                     | User            |
+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
.

format STDOUT =
| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< | @<<<<<<<<<<<<<< |
$file, $owner
.

format STDOUT_BOTTOM =
+----------------------------------------------------------+-----------------+
.
```

Reference:
[shift](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/shift),
[glob](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/glob),
[stat](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/stat),
[getpwuid](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/getpwuid),
[write](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/write),
[format](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform)

Comment: Could you add more comments to the code? I've first started using perl yesterday

Comment: Do you really want to recommend people use formats in 2021? :-)

Comment: @Dave Cross -- did I recommended use formats? I do not recall it, I just used format to show result -- if it exists and does the job then why not to use it. You could post your answer with more modern solution if you inclined in doing so. I still find that for perl newcomers _format_ is very easy to comprehend and does not require deep perl experience.

Comment: @DaveCross -- your comment would have more value if you suggested __something__ as a replacement of `format`, just to prove your point.

Comment: Nothing wrong with formats (though `Perl6::Form` is often nicer if non-core modules are on the table)

Comment: Modern Perl? Now I am curious 

Comment: @row - [Modern Perl 4 edition](http://modernperlbooks.com/books/modern_perl_2016/index.html), webpage [modern perl](http://modernperlbooks.com/), [Raku - Perl 6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raku_(programming_language)), [Raku](https://www.raku.org/)

Comment: @PolarBear: When you're obviously talking to a beginner, then just using a feature will be seen as a recommendation for that feature.  It's clear from the discussion here and [over on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/perl/comments/ns2v2s/code_in_perl/) that this suggestion confused the user. I would have stuck with a simple `print()` as used in the question.

Comment: @DaveCross - in my personal opinion the beginner should widen his circle of knowledge as broad as he/she can, otherwise he stuck with `print()` for rest of his life.  It is more wise to give a reference to a source which demonstrates and explains why some approach has an advantage over other. For example online book [Modern Perl](https://www.programmer-books.com/modern-perl-4th-edition-pdf/) is a good source of such knowledge. If a good free online source is available then it should be used to maximum of it's potential.

Comment: @PolarBear: Oh, I agree that it's usually a good idea to gain as much knowledge as possible. But maybe not really old Perl features that hardly anyone uses anymore :-) And, yes, it's great that people make free resources available online. But the Perl Bookshelf that you like to recommend is rather old (and there are only pirate copies available online). There's a good list of legally-available free Perl books on [perl.org](https://www.perl.org/books/library.html).

Comment: @DaveCross -- pirate source is Ukrainian website (it is a country of thieves and corruption) which is supported by USA and Europe. Ukraine is famous for stealing transit of natural gas from Russian Federation to Europe (year 2006 when southern Europe was cut from gas supply). I would be happy to hear that Ukrainian pirate sources will be shut down -- this website was online for past 12-15 years. The best source is perldoc -- but newcomers have not idea how to use it and turn to Google instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the chomp function to remove trailing newline (\n) from the user input.

```
my $directory = <STDIN>; #"/media";
chomp($directory);
```

Comment: Can't modify <HANDLE> in chomp at test.pl line 9, near "<STDIN>)"
Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors (#1)
    (F) You aren't allowed to assign to the item indicated, or otherwise try
    to change it, such as with an auto-increment.
    
Uncaught exception from user code:
 Can't modify <HANDLE> in chomp at test.pl line 9, near "<STDIN>)"
 Execution of test.pl aborted due to compilation errors

Comment: @row `chomp(my $dir = <STDIN>)` works though.

Comment: @row: You're right that you usually need to `chomp()` input in order to remove the newline. But that's not the problem here. As the value of `$directory` (with its newline attached) is passed to `qx(ls $directory)`, the extra newline is effectively ignored. Try it for yourself - `perl -lE '$dir = ".\n"; say qx(ls $dir)'`